# Is imagecreatefrompng safe to fetch external image?

Tags: php

I'm wondering whether the function imagecreatefrompng (and its relatives) are safe?

As in, if I where to fetch an external image file using this function, and the image contains malicous code, will this code be exetued on my server?

Example:

```
 <?php
if($_GET['pass'] != 'IamAW') die();

// Accepted Filetypes
$Accepted = array('png');

$File = $_GET['file'];

$Filetype = end(explode('.', $File));

if(!in_array($Filetype, $Accepted)) {
die('Fil-type ikke valid');
}

$im = imagecreatefrompng($File);


header('Content-Type: image/'. $Filetype);
imagepng($im);

imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's doable, but why even bother?

You're sucking down a remote PNG, decompressing to a raw format in memory, then recompressing to PNG, without having done ANYTHING to the image. You risk running out of memory if it ends up being a "big" PNG (e.g. a 1280x1024 32bit PNG  will require 5 megabytes of ram.

You'd be better off doing:

```
echo file_get_contents($remote_image_url);
```

saving you the decompress/recompress time.